# Dynamically create PHP if condition

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a form with multiple fields a user can search by. How do I dynamically write the if condition based on the fields selected by user?

E.g. I have 3 fields as follows:

```
$categoryId = $_REQUEST['category_id'];
$locationId = $_REQUEST['location_id'];
$statusId = $_REQUEST['status_id'];
```

If the user selected category_id and location_id  and status_id then my if statement would be should be as follows:

```
if (!empty($categoryId) && !empty($locationId) && !empty($statusId)) {
  if (isInTaxonomy($recordId, $categoryId) && isInTaxonomy($recordId, $locationId) && isInTaxonomy($recordId, $statusId) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

if the user selected category_id  and location_id then my if statmeent would be as follows:

```
if (!empty($categoryId) && !empty($locationId)) {
  if (isInTaxonomy($recordId, $categoryId) && isInTaxonomy($recordId, $locationId) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

if the user only selected category_id  then my if statmeent would be as follows:

```
if (!empty($categoryId)) {
  if (isInTaxonomy($recordId, $categoryId)) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

As you can see I'm having to implement every possible combination of fields a user can select to build all the different conditions.

I was thinking of doing something like the following but that just give me a string and I don't want to use eval to execute it:

```
$filter = [(!empty($categoryId) ? '(isInTaxonomy($recordId, $categoryId))' : ''),
         (!empty($locationId) ? '(isInTaxonomy($recordId, $locationId))' : '')];

$condition = implode(' && ', array_filter($filter));

if (eval("return $condition;")) {
   // Do something
}
```

Is there a way to dynamically generate all the condition using more concise code without having to resort to Eval?

Answer (score 1):

I presume you can use the following approach - define available keys and iterate over them, while iterate - collect some data, for example like this:

```
$keys = ['category_id', 'location_id', 'status_id'];

$operationAllowed = true;
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    if (!empty($_REQUEST[$key])) {
        $operationAllowed = $operationAllowed && isInTaxonomy($recordId, $_REQUEST[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the `&&` do in the following line `$operationAllowed = $operationAllowed && because it doesn't work?

Comment: This is just one of approaches, you join results of `isInTaxonomy`. So, whether you get `false` in some `isInTaxonomy` call, operation will not be allowed. You can do something else - like storing correct items in array or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You could add them to an array and loop the array (or keep them in the array and loop there).

```
$categoryId = $_REQUEST['category_id'];
$locationId = $_REQUEST['location_id'];
$statusId = $_REQUEST['status_id'];
// This can be done in different ways, I kept your "style" since you may have other reasons to extract the values
$arr =[$categoryId, $locationId, $statusId];

$arr = array_filter($arr); // remove empty values
$return[] = false; // set 0 key to false. First iteration will overwrite it
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    if (isInTaxonomy($recordId, $val)) {
         $return[$key] = true;
    }
}

if(array_diff($return, [true])) {
    // Don't do something (?)
}else{
    // Do something
    // (All is true)
}
```

Because I use array_filter then it will not test an empty value which will return false.

I rethought my code.
If all three is empty then my previous code would return true, which would be wrong (I guess).
So instead I start with false statement and add the true/false to an array then after the loop I see if I got any false return values with array_diff.
Array_diff will remove all true, if the return array has any values then at least one value in the loop was false.

Comment: so where do I add the code to do something - is that within the foreach block after the if statement?

Comment: The return will tell you if you should do something or not.

Comment: @adam78 I don't know if you noticed, but I made quite a change to my answer a few hours ago.

Answer (score -1):

This evaluates to the same results:

```
$categoryId = $_REQUEST['category_id'];
$locationId = $_REQUEST['location_id'];
$statusId = $_REQUEST['status_id'];

if( (empty($categoryId) || isInTaxonomy($recordId, $categoryId)) &&
    (empty($locationId) || isInTaxonomy($recordId, $locationId)) &&
    (empty($statusId)   || isInTaxonomy($recordId, $statusId))) {
    // Do Something
}
```

It's separated by lines, each variable is a line. If the variable is empty, line evaluates to `true` (without checking `isInTaxonomy`), and goes on the next one, if variable is not empty, then the second condition is checked, `isInTaxonomy` is evaluated, if it's `true`, validation goes on to the next line, if it's `false`, it stops.

---

Edit: you can also use this approach on a for loop

```
$args = ['category_id', 'location_id', 'status_id'];

$valid = true;
foreach ($args as $arg) {
    $valid &= empty($_REQUEST[$arg]) || isInTaxonomy($recordId, $_REQUEST[$arg]);
}

if($valid) {
    // Do Something
}
```